# How could I show placeholder inside html inputs?

Tags: python, html, css, django

I want to set placeholder inside text inputs, and I still don't know how to do this. I tried to add attributes but they didnt work and text is still showing above inputs. Here's my code:

forms.py

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.Charfield(widget = forms.TextInput),
    password = forms.Charfield(widget = forms.PasswordInput)
```

and that form is creating something like this:

html

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-8">   </div>
            <div class="col-4">

                
                
                    
                        <p><span style="font-size:50px; color:#ac3b61;">Welcome!</span></p>
                    
                    <form action="/account/login/" method="post">
                        <p><label for="id_username">Username:</label> <input type="text" name="username" autofocus="" autocapitalize="none" autocomplete="username" maxlength="150" required="" id="id_username"></p>
<p><label for="id_password">Password:</label> <input type="password" name="password" autocomplete="current-password" required="" id="id_password"></p>
                        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="gkh34TNSATaWHP3f3c9Qmp1msf6nazSd9hAoKsTPlHtMWFN4nNIYOwkpx9iXcCer">
                        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/account/"> 
                        
                        
                        <p><input type="submit" value="Login"></p>
                        
                        <p><a href="/account/password_reset/">Forgot your password?</a></p>
                        <p>Don't have an account? Register <a href="/account/register/">here</a>. </p>
                        
                    </form>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Did you try the attribute "placeholder"?

Comment: add something like this? <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="enter your username" >

Comment: there is a comma in your forms.py at the end of the line. Please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `attrs` option in the fields like this:

```
class LoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget = forms.TextInput(
                      attrs={ 'placeholder': 'Enter Username' }
               )),
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput(
                      attrs={ 'placeholder': 'Enter Password' }
               ))
```

Comment: You have a mispelling, it's `forms.CharField` not `forms.Charfield`

Comment: @user15117822 take a look at the [django form widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#widget).